# What could have added `[url ...] insteadOf=...` to my .gitconfig file?

Tags: git, github

Lately, I get weird errors from git on the command line and GitHub Desktop. Let's focus on command line (the repo is forked on GitHub):

```
$ git fetch upstream
repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Weird. When I examine the URL via `git config --get remote.upstream.url`, I get the correct URL. However, `git remote show upstream` gives the same error as previous `fetch`. When I give `git remote show -n upstream`, I get some messed up URL's:

```
* remote upstream
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:doekman/mac-bin.gitgithub.com/secretGeek/ok-bash.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:doekman/mac-bin.gitgithub.com/secretGeek/ok-bash.git
```

The first URL (git@bitbucket.org:doekman/mac-bin.git) is my own repository, but unrelated to the one I'm working with, and the other part (github.com/secretGeek/ok-bash.git) is the upstream URL I need.

GitHub desktop detects the error, and suggests fixing it, but when I press fix, nothing happens.

The weird thing, the `.git/config` file looks allright?

I can reclone this repository, and reconfigure upstream, but I want to know how this happened and/or how this works.

**update**

Since a text-search of `mac-bin` within the `.git` folder didn't do a thing, I looked around, and I found the following had been added to my `~/.gitconfig` file.

What could have caused these lines being added. I sure didn't add these:

```
[url "git@bitbucket.org:doekman/mac-bin.git"]
    insteadOf = https://
[url "https://<GITUSERNAME>@"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

Comment: What are you using to view `.git/config`? Does your OS have special kinds of file encodings, and/or does your editor do weird file encoding tricks? Git "wants" `.git/config` to contain UTF-8 encoded data with no byte order mark.

Comment: Aha, didn't consider the `insteadOf` thing from a separate configuration. That's kind of horrifying :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper insteadOf would need more than the URL scheme (https:// or SSH://), but a proper URL to replace)

If you can, delete those insteadof directive from your config file.

Also, check for any other similar values with:

```
git config -l --show-origin
```